# Laravel If user is not logged redirect to login, after login redirect him to previous route

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route that is protected by `Auth::check()`.  So, if it passes, user can access it, if no - user is `redirect()->route('login);`
When user enters his credentials I want to redirect him back to the route that he tried to achieve

MY LOGIN CONTROLLER :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        session(['url.intended' => url()->previous()]);
        $this->redirectTo = session()->get('url.intended');

        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
        $data['is_active'] = true;
        return $data;
    }

     public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
            return $this->redirectTo();
        }

    }

}
```

MY RedirectIfAuthenticated Middleware :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

NOW THAT WORKS, When login, user is redirected back, but because of that, my previous feature breaks. I want that anyway, if you logged in and have a role `administrator` or `superadministrator` to redirect to  `/manage`

Comment: Please show some code that you have tried

Comment: Laravel does it out of the box for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing it by yourself using `Auth::check()` to protect the route then use the following:

```
return redirect()->guest(route('login')); // Don't use redirect()->route('login)
```

instead of `redirect()->route('login)`. Then, in the successful login, use:

```
return redirect()->intended('/home'); // home is the default/fallback url
```

You may need to change the default url depending on your route declarations.

### Update: (after the question edit):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::check() && (Auth::user()->int_role_id == Roles::ROLE_USER)) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

In your `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`, just, use the following:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home'; // this is default/fallback path
```

`Laravel` uses `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers::sendLoginResponse` which uses the `intended` method, so you don't need to do anything else (hope you are not using very old version).

### Updated again after another edit by the `OP`

In your `RedirectIfAuthenticated`, try this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        // Replace the ? marks with appropriate value
        if ($user->int_role_id == ? || $user->int_role_id == ?) {
            return redirect('/manage');
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: I didn't get it. I added some code to this question, please review it. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried also with  LaraTrust syntax that I used for Authentication roles and Permissions.
` if ($user->hasRole('superadministrator') || $user->hasRole('administrator'))` instead of 
`if ($user->int_role_id == ? || $user->int_role_id == ?)`
and anyway...everytime it redirects me just `back()`

Comment: I also put redirect "dummy-text" in each function, and didn't find a function that after login will return me that dummy text. So, for me it seems like that functions have not any effect on that processes :/

Comment: Oh, God. I solved it by rewriting `authenticated` method of `AuthenticatedUsers` in LoginController like so :
`protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if ($user->hasRole('superadministrator') || $user->hasRole('administrator')) {
            return redirect()->route('manage.dashboard');
        }
    }`

Comment: Glad to know you solved it. Yes, that's another approach, after successful login, the `authenticated` method gets called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in ur middleware

```
if (Auth::check() && (Auth::user()->int_role_id == Roles::ROLE_USER)) {
        return $next($request);
    }else if (!Auth::check() ){
        $url = Request()->path();
        Session::put('loginRedirect', $url);
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

In your login controller do this

```
if(Session::get('loginRedirect')){
    $url = Session::get('loginRedirect');
    Session::forget('loginRedirect');
    return Redirect::intended(url($url));
}
return Redirect::intended(route('user.get_home'));
```

**UPDATE** PLEASE UPDATE UR ROUTE OR URL...

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return $next($request);
    }else if (!Auth::check() ){
        $url = Request()->path();
        Session::put('loginRedirect', $url);
        return redirect('YOUR LOGIN ROUTE OR URL');
    }
}
```

Login Controller

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if(Session::get('loginRedirect')){
        $url = Session::get('loginRedirect');
        Session::forget('loginRedirect');
        return Redirect::intended(url($url));
    }
    return Redirect::intended(route('YOUR INTENDED URL OR ROUTE after user is logged in'));
}
```

Comment: So, I have to do it on each route? Is there an easiest way to achieve it ?

Comment: Y each route ??

Comment: Just login right you are redirecting ur user to login if not logged in so only update the login controller and auth middleware

Comment: em, sorry, again, where exactly to put the first code snippet?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that, use that code in middleware, redirectifunauthenticated middleware .

Comment: I edited my post with code of this two files. Please, say me where to add that to not break it all :)

I already edited in past that files, to make it like : If you sign up with administrator/superadministrator user, redirect to `back-end administration stuff`, else, to homepage. Now I want that when guest is on the site and wanted to visit a route that has admitted only for users, to redirect him to login page, and when he gets authenticated, access that route that he desires

Comment: Replace the firstcode in the handle function of middleware, and  second code in redirectpath  of login controller

Comment: I tried your code entirely, now when I just go to homepage, it loads 5 seconds, and when I press to go to login page, it returns me :

`
This page isn’t working
localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
`

Comment: Edited again, review please

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply use this,

```
return Redirect::back();
```

And if you want to redirect back with some message or data, You can use

```
return Redirect::back()->with();
```

In **`with()`** you can pass any message or data like

```
return Redirect::back()->with('message', 'Success');
```

This should be used for redirecting to the previous location. **`back()`** is Laravel helper function. This feature utilizes the session.